# VSCode extension throws regex indices error only when other extension is enabled

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, es2022

### Background

I am working on an extension ([vscode-color-blocks](https://github.com/zimonitrome/vscode-color-blocks)) that uses [RegExp match indices](https://inspiredwebdev.com/everything-new-in-es2022/#regexp-match-indices) (new in ES2022). This means I am using a regex string with the `d` flag to get indices (relational positions) of each capture group in my regex ([source](https://github.com/zimonitrome/vscode-color-blocks/blob/main/src/helpers/colorBlockRegex.ts#L30)):

```js
export const colorBlockRegex = new RegExp(regexString, 'd');
```

This means that a successful regex match object will have a `.indices` attribute that I can then use ([source](https://github.com/zimonitrome/vscode-color-blocks/blob/main/src/decorationRangeHandler.ts#L110-L126)):

```js
const match = colorBlockRegex.exec(comment.content);
if (!match) continue;
console.log(match.indices);
```

### Problem

All of this works fine when I am using the extension on it's own and even together with some other extensions. But VSCode behaves like this new regex feature is not available once I install an extension named [Todo Tree](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.todo-tree). At that point my extension crashes and I get the following error:

```
stack trace: SyntaxError: Invalid flags: d
    at _ (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:114:74341)
    at Array.<anonymous> (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:114:3580)
    at Object.parse (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:114:71938)
    at Object.parse (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:1:12529)
    at Object.parse (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:114:415)
    at i (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:52:165)
    at Array.get [as indices] (...\.vscode\extensions\gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215\dist\extension.js:52:2895)
    at DecorationRangeHandler.addNewDecorationRanges (...\vscode-color-blocks\dist\extension.js:1735:95)
```

The stack trace is a little confusing as it steps from `gruntfuggly.todo-tree-0.0.215` into my extension `vscode-color-blocks`.

Otherwise there must be something wrong with how these two extensions are running on different versions on Javascript?

Comment: Is there a conflict in function names, maybe? Do you have `_` as a function somewhere?

Comment: @vanowm good idea, but I don't have any function named `_` specifically. Neither does todo-tree seem to have any function named `addNewDecorationRanges` or similar. Even then, the two extension should not be able to access each others' objects/classes/functions should they?

Comment: what happens at `todotree::extension.js:52:2895`

Comment: @rioV8 it is an obfuscated file too big to paste into Pastebin, but I copied the relevant block: https://pastebin.com/mMbyc5Ht
`todotree::extension.js:52:2895` is the position between `=` and `i` in the code `if(void 0===u){const{measurementRegExp:o,groupInfos:l}=i(e);` near the end.

Comment: Todo Tree seems to have a polyfill for what I, maybe naively, am trying to to use from the vanilla vscode JS library https://github.com/Gruntfuggly/todo-tree/blob/2a7f7318903f5ae268e782ac82b27d2258ddc59c/package.json#L1170. 
They must be clashing with each other somehow but I wonder why or how?